# How to do an API call to Google Cloud Vision TEXT_DETECTION on Expo React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, google-cloud-vision

I am trying to do an API call to Google Cloud Vision. What should my request body look like?

I tried reading the documentation on how to format the request body but I am not getting any luck.

This is my request body

```
let image = this.fileToBase64().done();

let body = JSON.stringify({
    requests: [
        {
            image: {
                content: image
            },
            features: [
                { type: "TEXT_DETECTION", maxResults: "5"},
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

This is my call

```
let response = await fetch("https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=" + GOOGLE_API_KEY, {
        method: "post",
        body: body,
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
    }
);
```

I am expecting a complete response in JSON with status code 200 but instead I am getting the response JSON with message "Request must specify image and features." and status code 400

Comment: Can you try without maxResults. As it does not apply when type is TEXT_DIRECTION as per their documentation. Here is the link https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/Feature

Comment: Thanks I managed with an answer I provided

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem was that the image content was empty as I did console.log(image). I just added the `let image = await this.fileToBase64().done();` s the fileToBase64 is async